# Ruby On Rails html5 storage offline CRUD application with or without ActiveScaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, activescaffold, offlineapps

I am currently building a web application using Ruby On Rails with ActiveScaffold.
And I would like to know whether there is any plugin/library which would make possible to enable my Rails application to work offline e.g. the user can browse some of the data and make changes while the user is disconnected, after the user gets online again the data would be simply synced.

Answer (score 5):

Check out Ryan Bate's excellent Railscasts here:

[Offline Apps Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1) covers rack-offline

[Offline Apps Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/248-offline-apps-part-2) covers jquery-tmpl and jquery-offline.

Or, read them on Asciicasts

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/248-offline-apps-part-2